# Validate logical/boolean expression in Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, validation, logical-operators, boolean-operations

I have a list of json files in which  one field have expressions. I want to validate those fields by using python. I want to check if they are written in correct format or not for e.g. The script should give error if expression is like this- "=<"  instead of "<=". And I want to find all such error possibilities.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "id": "1",
    "description": "Its a test",
    "expressions": "{var_a} = 5",
    "expressions": "{var_b} = 6",
    "expressions": "{var_a} => {var_b}",
    "unittest": "test.txt"
}
```

I want my python script to catch that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this. I have taken the line provided and something along these lines might help you.

```
import json
import re

data = '{ "name": "test", "id": "1", "description": "Its a test", "expressions": "{var_a} = 5", "expressions": "{var_b} = 6", "expressions": "{var_a} => {var_b}", "unittest": "test.txt" }'

pData = json.loads(data)

if re.search('>=',pData['expressions']):
    print 'OK'
else:
    print 'Error'
```

Comment: That's a static way, I want it to be dynamic, as I have around 2000 such json files and I don't know what kind of error a user can made in that expression. So I just want to validate the correct expression format.

Comment: Are you only checking the 'expression'? If so how about getting all possible operators in a list and check the operator in the file against that?

Comment: yeah, that can be the solution of taking all the valid expressions in a list, and I didn't got your last comment. I am assigning  a  = 5 and B = 6, then comparing both variables. Last expression should be {var_a} >= {var_b}.

Comment: Please ignore that comment, that's me not understanding the code.